# FullCalendar Select doesn't work if using fullcalendar.js instead of fullcalendar.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

All,
I'm using the example that is in the fullcalendar download, however I'd like to use the fullcalendar.js instead of the fullcalendar.min.js. When I make this change though the select option doesn't work (I can't select any time range and the pop up doesn't come up).

Any ideas what has to change in the fullcalender.js file to make this work?

**EDIT** I'm using the following code for my select:

```
selectable: true,
selectHelper: true,
select: function(start, end, allDay) {
    var title = prompt('Event Title:');
    calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
},
```

**EDIT #2** The issue seems to be with the selectHelper. If I comment out that part I can select the time that I want to use but it doesn't have the nice overlay. Here is the code from fullcalendar.js that does this:

```
function renderSlotSelection(startDate, endDate) {
    var helperOption = opt('selectHelper');
    coordinateGrid.build();
    if (helperOption) {
        var col = dayDiff(startDate, t.visStart) * dis + dit;
        if (col >= 0 && col < colCnt) { // only works when times are on same day
            var rect = coordinateGrid.rect(0, col, 0, col, slotContent); // only for horizontal coords
            var top = timePosition(startDate, startDate);
            var bottom = timePosition(startDate, endDate);
            if (bottom > top) { // protect against selections that are entirely before or after visible range
                rect.top = top;
                rect.height = bottom - top;
                rect.left += 2;
                rect.width -= 5;
                if ($.isFunction(helperOption)) {
                    var helperRes = helperOption(startDate, endDate);
                    if (helperRes) {
                        rect.position = 'absolute';
                        rect.zIndex = 8;
                        selectionHelper = $(helperRes)
                            .css(rect)
                            .appendTo(slotContent);
                    }
                }else{
                    rect.isStart = true; // conside rect a "seg" now
                    rect.isEnd = true;   //
                    selectionHelper = $(slotSegHtml(
                        {
                            title: '',
                            start: startDate,
                            end: endDate,
                            className: ['fc-select-helper'],
                            editable: false
                        },
                        rect
                    ));
                    selectionHelper.css('opacity', opt('dragOpacity'));
                }
                if (selectionHelper) {
                    slotBind(selectionHelper);
                    slotContent.append(selectionHelper);
                    setOuterWidth(selectionHelper, rect.width, true); // needs to be after appended
                    setOuterHeight(selectionHelper, rect.height, true);
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        renderSlotOverlay(startDate, endDate);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why this wouldn't work but it isn't. Any ideas on what to change?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bigger issue and the issue revolves around a new issue in how jQuery does things. The issue is caused by a change in the regular expression which is used to normalize 'mouse event properties' in the Event object: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L7

There is a thread going on here to monitor this solution:

http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=1168

This fix doesn't work in IE however.